# How to get value of custom lookup field.?

Tags: client-object-model

I have code here,

```
    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, Fruits)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + '\nFruits: ' + ???;
```

how can I get all values of Fruit as fruit is a custom field.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends whether Lookup Field is multi-valued or single-valued.

### How to retrieve Lookup field via CSOM in SharePoint 2013

`SP.LookupField` value is represented as [SP.FieldLookupValue object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407817%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
//Get LookupField value
var categoryValue = item.get_item('Category');
var catLabel = categoryValue.get_lookupValue();
var catId = categoryValue.get_lookupId();
```

Multiple `SP.LookupField` value is represented as array of [SP.FieldLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407817%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

```
//Get Multiple Lookup Field value
var categoryValues = item.get_item('Categories'); 
for(var i = 0; i < categoryValues.length; i++) {
   var categoryValue = categoryValues[i];
   var catLabel = categoryValue.get_lookupValue();
   var catId = categoryValue.get_lookupId();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `oListItem.get_item('Fruits').get_lookupValue()` where `Fruits` is the internal name of the field.