# Retrieve list value with more than 2 look up field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, napa

I have a list 'NewsList' with columns Title, ShortDescription,Image ,Programs,Division and Tag.

Here, Programs,Division and Tag are lookup fields with same list name.
When I try to retrieve the values, Title and ShortDescription are coming fine. But in Image, Programs,Division and Tag, its displaying [object Object].
I am a beginner to SharePoint and NAPA. Kindly help.

Below is the snippet of the codes I am using.

```
 function getitems() {
     var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
     var context1 = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(context1, hostUrl);
     web = hostcontext.get_web();

     var selectedList = "NewsList";
     var selectedListTitle = web.get_lists().getByTitle(selectedList);  
     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
     camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><ViewFields>" +
                           "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                           "<FieldRef Name='ShortDescription' />" +
                           "<FieldRef Name='Image' />" +
                           "<FieldRef Name='Programs' />" +
                           "<FieldRef Name='Division' />" +
                           "<FieldRef Name='Tag' />" +
                           "</ViewFields></View>')");
     listItemCollection = selectedListTitle.getItems(camlQuery);
     context.load(listItemCollection, "Include(Title, ShortDescription, Image, Programs, Division, Tag)");
     context.executeQueryAsync(onGetItemsSuccess, onGetItemsFail);
    }

    function onGetItemsSuccess(sender, args) {
      var listItemEnumerator = listItemCollection.getEnumerator();

      var strTbl = '';
      strTbl = strTbl + '<table><tr><td>Title</td><td>ShortDescription</td><td>Image</td><td>Programs</td><td>Division</td><td>Tag</td></tr>';

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();


        strTbl = strTbl + '<tr><td>' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '</td><td>' + oListItem.get_item('ShortDescription') + '</td>' + '<td>' + oListItem.get_item('Image') + '</td> +
                            '<td>' + oListItem.get_item('Programs') + '</td><td>' + oListItem.get_item('Division') + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + oListItem.get_item('Tag') + '</td></tr>';
    }
    strTbl = strTbl + '</table>';
      $('#dvNews').html(strTbl);
     }
```

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 1):

For lookup columns use `get_lookupValue()` to get the lookup information. Example: `oListItem.get_item('Programs').get_lookupValue()`

**UPDATE**

In case lookup field supports multiple values, use this code:

```
//Get Multiple Lookup Field value
var categoryValues = item.get_item('Categories'); 
for(var i = 0; i < categoryValues.length; i++) {
   var categoryValue = categoryValues[i];
   var catLabel = categoryValue.get_lookupValue();
   var catId = categoryValue.get_lookupId();
}
```

Source: [How to get value of custom lookup field.?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93478/how-to-get-value-of-custom-lookup-field)

Comment: Thank you Nadeem. But its still not working. Do I have to add something in caml query also?

Comment: Are your fields single lookup type or multi lookup types. Also, yu dont need to use `camlQuery.set_viewXml` as you are referencing the fields in the load statement.

Comment: its single lookup

Comment: Are you getting any error. Try using developer tools to debug the code.