# add/remove list UI - what does the data look like?

Tags: list, javascript

I have to retrieve data from a SP list using javascript.

This list has got a field which is being set using an "add/remove list" (with add and remove buttons in between two listboxes, you know)..

Now when I call for its data using

```
oListItem.get_item('MyField');
```

what does the data recieved look like? 
The add/remove field contents come from an other list.

I haven't got access to SP myself and am a bit in the blind here..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call the "add/remove list field" is actually a "multi lookup field".
You can retrieve values from it as described in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/93486/35604 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698793/3439544.