# get name alone from people picker to a usercontrol

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to fetch name alone from people picker in a sharepoint custom list and display it in a gridview- usercontrol. currently Iam getting whole details which include ID and name(eg: 19;# lastname, firstname(company)). But I need name alone. How can I do that. Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using SharePoint designer?

Comment: yes, Iam using sharepoint designer.

Comment: Please refer this Answer. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93478/how-to-get-value-of-custom-lookup-field

Comment: sorry I'm new to this programming. Am I able to get name alone by using lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no method to get name alone from a list and display in grid view.

So finally I did by concatenating.

```
foreach (SPListItem itm in itmcoll)    
{    
     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();    
     string ProjMangrLogged = Convert.ToString(itm["Project ManagerID"]);
     int start = ProjMangrLogged.IndexOf("#") + 1;  
     int end=ProjMangrLogged.IndexOf("(",start);

     string ProjMangr = ProjMangrLogged.Substring(start, end - start);

     dr["Item Project ManagerID"] = ProjMangr;

     dt.Rows.Add(dr);   
}
```