# How to refer to a lookup field in a returned CAML query?

Tags: javascript, column, internal-name

I know how to refer to a standard field in the OnSuccess function of a .executeQueryAsync call using a CAML query;

```
qryItems.itemAt(1).get_item('Mailto')
```

However, I have another column that is a lookup field returned from an associated field. For example;

[image]

The field I want to reference is *Preferred E-mail*.

I have tried;

```
qryItems.itemAt(1).get_item('Preferred E-mail')
```

But this does not work. I have tried getting the internal field name from the URL (Field=Account%5Fx003a%5FPreferred%5Fx0020%5FE%5F) and passed it through a URL Decoder to get *Account_x003a_Preferred_x0020_E_*. This does seem oddly truncated and;

```
qryItems.itemAt(1).get_item('Account_x003a_Preferred_x0020_E_')
```

This works to a degree, but returns an object rather than the text of the e-mail address itself.

Comment: Something helpful: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93478/how-to-get-value-of-custom-lookup-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Have you tried using

```
  qryItems.itemAt(1).get_item('Preferred E-mail').get_lookupValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting lookup values use below:

```
var columnFieldValue = qryItems.itemAt(1).get_item("columnName");
var lookupValue = columnFieldValue.get_lookupValue();
var lookupId = columnFieldValue.get_lookupId();
```